# SSRS Report Grouping (Parent and Child)

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to establish a grouping for CSG1 and Section to look like below where the CSG is the parent then the Section is the Child and the expression will be the detail. Somehow, after I defined the parent and child group the section is aligned with the group. Section should be at the bottom of CSG, and I cannot find the correct properties to do this.

[image]

Output

[image]

My .rdl template set-up. I cannot make the field section go at the bottom of CSG field.

[image]

Comment: based on the design view, the group was created without any issue, could you provider the `preview` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the CSG Row Group, right mouse click, Add Group, select Adjacent below, on the group by select "Section"

Comment: I just have to delete extra columns to align them into 1 column after I established the grouping.